# A survey of classical results/theorems for mathematical biology and biomathematics.

Tags: reference-request, biology

I am looking for some source that gathers most of the major results of mathematical biology before 2000. I have found various books that contains small subset of this, for examples, "Mathematical models in population biology and epidemiology" by Fred Brauer and Castillo-Chavez, and "Mathematics in population biology" by Horst Thieme.

To be specific, I am looking for more of theoretical and general results (applicable to all mathematical biology - not specific to one of its subfields). Something along the line of "Convergence results and a Poincaré-Bendixson trichotomy for asymptotically autonomous differential equations" by Thieme, H.R. J. Math. Biol. (1992) 30: 755. doi:10.1007/BF00173267.

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you are asking for? Mathematical biology is huge. Do you want theorems on knots and the structure of DNA? Graph theory and slime mold? Genes, alleles, and cancer cells and the replicator dynamics? What books have you surveyed?

Comment: I will make an edit to address this shortly.